# I don't think my macbook can sense the right temperature

Tags: macbook-pro

I downloaded fan control recently due to my macbook heating up quickly however the fan control app keeps saying my macbook is 0 degrees even when it is burning hot! so the fan can only go up to 3500 rpm which is the fastest i can make as the base fan level.

Comment: I would say the fan control app sucks :)

Answer (score 0):

Before making bold claims it could be the fan control app that you downloaded.

Try installing [this free app](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TemperatureMonitor.html) to see what temperature readout you get with it.

As for your computer been very hot, anything above 50 Celsius feels hot to people. Your computer can operate up to 100 Degree Celsius (internally, the CPU) at which you would have blisters if you touch it.

If you have a household thermometer use it to check. The Mac body is designed no to exceed 60 Celsius since people could end up having burns and sue Apple for that.

If you still think your Mac goes way to hot, bring it in for service.